# Copying the color of an Excel sheet tab to a cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a few hundred worksheets in an excel file with one worksheet referencing all of the others (a tracker sheet). The other sheets have color-coded tabs based on completion, and I want to reference that in the tracker sheet. Is there any way to find the color of a worksheet tab, and add it to it's respective tracker line in the tracker sheet?

Comment: You should show your work first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
  MsgBox ws.Tab.Color
```

This will return the value of the colour as Hex/RGB Depending on whether it's primary or not

This was to display in a msgbox for testing

Answer (score 1):

I created a [sample worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsplU.jpg) to try and replicate your problem. There is a 'TrackerSheet', and several other blank WorkSheets with colored tabs. I don't know what your naming convention is for the sheets so I just used "Sheets"; I also used a button to execute the following code but you can use it in the event you're using:

```
Sub Button2_Click()
   Dim tabColorIndex As Variant, index As Integer

   'For all of your sheets being tracked
   For index = 1 To 3
      'Retrieve the tab's colorIndex at index
      tabColorIndex = Sheets("Sheet" & index).Tab.colorIndex
      'Set the cells' colors in the respective row from columns A to F
      Sheets("TrackerSheet").Range("A" & index & ":F" & index).Interior.colorIndex = tabColorIndex
   Next index
End Sub
```

This colors the rows as shown in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple thing to do actually,

```
  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SheetABC").Tab.Color '<= parse the color of the tab
```

You can then manipulate this color to your needs using a variablE.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use:

```
dim ws as worksheet
ws.tab.color=' numerical value of the tab color you are looking for
```

Set that in an if statement and use a counter to keep track of the tabs of the set color. You can loop through all the worksheets in the workbook as well:

```
for each sht in application.worksheet

next sht
```